# Does node fs support copying files using a globbing pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cp

I need to execute `cp src/main/css/* ./dist`.  I found [cpy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpy) on NPM, but just curious if Node supports this natively now?

Comment: It doesn’t.︁︁︁︁

Comment: You can see all the filesystem functions here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native node fs module does not support it ATM, as can be seen here:
[Node FS API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: you can use fs.readdirSync to read all dir's files and check if this file is directory or file if file copy it immediately or if directory you need to use recursion to check if file is directory or file you can use fs.stat()